# Dynamic file name with multiple image upload

Tags: php, image, upload

I am using class.upload.php and I have the code all working except I want to extend the my script to work with multiple file uploads I read the documentation on the website and was able to figure it out. However I need my image files output like m_1234_1, m_1234_3, m_1234_4 and so on... How does one make it so that `$handle->file_new_name_body = $new_name;` starts with `$new_name.'1'` and continues adding 1 to every iteration?

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // define variables
        $new_name = 'm_'.$id.'_';
        $thumb_name = 't_'.$id.'_';
        $ext = 'jpg';
        $upload_path = 'images/uploads/'.$id.'/'; // will not work with /images/
        $full_src = $upload_path.$new_name.'.'.$ext;
        // end define variables

        $files = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['userfile'] as $k => $l) {
         foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
         if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
           $files[$i] = array();
           $files[$i][$k] = $v;
         }
        }     

        foreach ($files as $file) {

            $handle = new upload($_FILES['userfile']);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                // save uploaded image 458 x 332
                $handle->file_new_name_body = $new_name;
                $handle->image_convert = $ext;
                $handle->allowed = array('image/*');
                $handle->jpeg_quality = 95;
                $handle->image_resize = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                    $handle->image_x = 458;
                    $handle->image_y = 332;
                $handle->file_overwrite = true;
                $handle->auto_create_dir = true;
                $handle->process($upload_path);
                if ($handle->processed) {
                    mysql_select_db($db);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE projects SET last_modified=NOW(), project_image_1 = '".$full_src."' WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="ec-messages messages-error">';
                    echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                // create thumbnail 104 x 76
                $handle->file_new_name_body = $thumb_name;
                $handle->image_convert = $ext;
                $handle->allowed = array('image/*');
                $handle->jpeg_quality = 90;
                $handle->image_resize = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                    $handle->image_x = 104;
                    $handle->image_y = 76;
                $handle->file_overwrite = true;
                $handle->auto_create_dir = true;
                $handle->process($upload_path);
                if ($handle->processed) {
                    echo '<div class="ec-messages messages-success">Image successfully uploaded and added to database (thumnails created)<br>Redirecting to <a href="projects.php?msg=insert">projects main</a>...</div><br><img src="'.$full_src.'" class="display-image">';
                    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='projects.php?msg=insert';\",2000);</script>";
                    include('Templates/footer_exit.php');
                    $handle->clean();
                    exit;
                } else {
                    // no error here, error will be handled by the first script
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    ?>
```

UPDATED (now working):

```
      <?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // define variables
    $ext = 'jpg';
    $upload_path = 'images/uploads/'.$id.'/'; // will not work with /images/
    // end define variables

    $files = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['userfile'] as $k => $l) {
     foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
     if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
       $files[$i] = array();
       $files[$i][$k] = $v;
     }
    }     
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($files as $file) {

        //$append = rand(100,99999);
        $new_name = 'm_'.$id;
        $thumb_name = 't_'.$id;
        $handle = new upload($file);
        if ($handle->uploaded) {
            // save uploaded image 458 x 332
            $count = $counter++;
            $nn = sprintf("%s_%d", $new_name, $count);
            $full_src = $upload_path.$nn.'.'.$ext;
            $handle->file_new_name_body = $nn;
            $handle->image_convert = $ext;
            $handle->allowed = array('image/*');
            $handle->jpeg_quality = 95;
            $handle->image_resize = true;
            $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle->image_x = 458;
                $handle->image_y = 332;
            $handle->file_overwrite = true;
            $handle->auto_create_dir = true;
            $handle->process($upload_path);
            if ($handle->processed) {
                mysql_select_db($db);
                mysql_query("UPDATE projects SET last_modified=NOW(), project_image_".$count." = '".$full_src."' WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
            } else {
                echo '<div class="ec-messages messages-error">';
                echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
                echo '</div>';
            }
            // create thumbnail 104 x 76
            $tn = sprintf("%s_%d", $thumb_name, $count);
            $handle->file_new_name_body = $tn;
            $handle->image_convert = $ext;
            $handle->allowed = array('image/*');
            $handle->jpeg_quality = 90;
            $handle->image_resize = true;
            $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle->image_x = 104;
                $handle->image_y = 76;
            $handle->file_overwrite = true;
            $handle->auto_create_dir = true;
            $handle->process($upload_path);
            if ($handle->processed) {
                echo 'Done!';
                /*
                echo '<div class="ec-messages messages-success">Image successfully uploaded and added to database (thumnails created)<br>Redirecting to <a href="projects.php?msg=insert">projects main</a>...</div><br><img src="'.$full_src.'" class="display-image">';
                echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='projects.php?msg=insert';\",2000);</script>";
                include('Templates/footer_exit.php');
                $handle->clean();
                exit;
                */
            } else {
                // no error here, error will be handled by the first script
            }
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might define

```
$new_name = 'm_'.$id.'_';
$counter = 1;              // File counter
```

at the beginning, and replace that line with

```
$handle->file_new_name_body = sprintf("%s.%d", $new_name, $counter++);
```

so that 'file' would become 'file.1.jpg', and so on.

Comment: i figured it out thanks to you, updated code above works! thanks for all ur help!